# Decoding a zip file downloaded from s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, character-encoding, md5

I'm trying to decode a zip file so i can create an md5 hash out of it.

When I run this

```
contents = response['Body'].read()
decoded = contents.decode('utf-8')
```

I get this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 10: invalid start byte
```

What worked for me is `IBM437`

```
contents.decode('IBM437')
```

The whole hashing flow works in AWS's `ContentMD5` check on upload

I'm not reformatting on how it's uploaded I'm just encoding it in a non utf-8 to create an md5 hash that works

What are the caveats of doing this in `IBM437`, since utf-8 seem like the "standard" type.

Comment: Zip files are binary data, they can't be meaningfully decoded as text.  Why not just hash the bytes?

Comment: If you want to calculate the has of a binary file, just calculate the has of `contents`, no need to coerce it into a string at all.

Answer (score 0):

As someone suggested in the comments. We don't have to convert the binary to a string.

So this would be the re-approach

```
contents = response['Body'].read()
md = hashlib.md5(contents).digest()
contents_md5 = base64.b64encode(md).decode('utf-8')
```